# HTML Parser for local HTML files

Tags: c#, html

I need to be able to parse an HTML template file (with the intention of injecting an SVG element into a html file, then converting it to pdf via wkhtmltopdf).

I know about the HTML Agility Pack, but it seems incapable of parsing local files (attempts to use file:// URIs have caused it to throw exceptions).

So, can anyone recommend a C# HTML parser for local HTML files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTML Agility Pack is fine for local files, check out this [example](http://html-agility-pack.net/from-file) from the docs.

Alternatively, load the content from the file into a string using something like [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) then pass it into `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(string html)`.

Comment: Seems I was overcomplicating it by trying to use file://

Answer (score 3):

How about using the `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml` function of HTML Agility Pack?

You could use the [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) to read the text into memory and pass it to the `LoadHtml` function.

Comment: reading the file contents using File.ReadAllText and then, HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(string fileContents) worked for me as far as I remember.