# HTML Agility Pack Causes Code to Stop Executing After Load Call

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am creating a small application to parse HTML of a page into variables so I can generate code for another proprietary application. I am using VB with HTMLAgilityPack for parsing. When I execute the load statement, no error are shown but all other code after that line simply fails to execute, as if it isn't even there.

```
Private Sub Importer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim strImportType As String
Dim strImportURL As String

strImportType = main.importType

strImportURL = main.importURL

Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
Dim content As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

content = web.Load(strImportURL)
```

Comment: Check the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2017) (`CTRL + ALT + I`). It logs all exceptions that are thrown, handled or not. Exceptions occurring in the `Load` event doesn't always break the application, so it's easy to miss.

Comment: @VisualVincent I see what you mean. I wouldn't have noticed that.

Exception thrown: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWebException' in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

I will note that strImportURL points to a local file. I have tried it with the raw path as well as the web browser generated file:// before the local path.

Comment: You can use the [Exception Settings window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017) to force VS to break on all exceptions. That should properly display the error for you (just remember to reset the changes in the window again when you are done).

Comment: @user3661293 This is easier: [HTML Parser for local HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061141/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton When actually running the comp[leted program it will be run against a live webpage. I was just using a local file for testing.

Comment: After changing the exception settings per Visual Vincent's suggestion, I got a more detailed error message: "URI formats not supported" for when the URL includes the file:// and cannot locate file without the file://. At this point I suspected the spaces were the problem as %20 is not able to be used as a space in Windows. I removed the spaces from the file and that fixed the issue. As I stated earlier I will be using a live web environment when not testing, so I don't need to adjust the code to account for spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Visual Vincent suggestion to open the Exceptions Settings and force VB to fail it allowed for more information. This issue was simply that the file was not being found due to spaces in the filename. Adding quotes around the filename resolved the issue.